# Safest modern filter for database insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, sql-injection

Temporarily ignoring prepared statements and other way of actually doing the insertion into a database, what is the best current way of sanitizing input before it gets inserted?

`function filter($s) {
    return htmlentities(addslashes($s));
}`

or

`function filter($t) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($t);
}`

Comment: In this instance `mysqli_real_escape_string` **but** binding parameters to prepared statements is much better : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is still the better method, but it is terrible compared to proper use of prepared statements. No form of string escaping should be tolerated in modern SQL applications.

Comment: `htmlentities` is totally wrong. The only purpose of that is to escape HTML when displaying it on a web page, it has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: being that sometimes content from the database has to be output on the page, should `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `htmlentities` be used in together for such data?

Comment: No, you should html encode content when displaying data on a html page, not when inserting the data to database.

Comment: Also, I don't see the point in this question. Prepared statements is the **only** way to protect against SQL injection, why would you not want to use that?

Answer (score 2):

> Temporarily ignoring prepared statements and other way of actually doing the insertion into a database,

Okay, let's put best practices that *actually* achieve security aside...

> what is the best current way of sanitizing input before it gets inserted?

This is a curious question! If you have mysqli, you *can* use prepared statements, so I don't understand the reason why anyone wouldn't use them?

Granted, there are a narrow set of use-cases where you need to accept user data and combine it with a SQL query. `LIMIT $foo` is a classic example (easiest solution: use PHP 7 and only accept an `int` to that parameter).

Another example is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2, 3, 4, 5)`. Once again, casting user input to an integer removes most of the attack surface here.

Integers are easy. What about strings?

Well, [read this at least once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2224584). You should be very familiar with charset attacks and ensure you're using a safe charset, safely.

As long as you follow the prescribed advice, yes, you can safely use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote()`.

**But seriously, use prepared statements.** You're less likely to make a mistake if you [separate data from code](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/gentle-introduction-application-security).

> ```
> function filter($s) {
>     return htmlentities(addslashes($s));
> }
> ```

Not only is this a bad idea for preventing SQLi, it's a [bad idea to attempt to strip XSS on insert](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html).

In closing, SQLi and XSS are solved problems, and the tools and strategies for [preventing SQLi](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) and the tools for [preventing XSS](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know) have virtually no overlap. Confuse them at your own peril.